# Export and import Data from Quickbase to csv file with perl script

Tags: perl, quickbase

I am try to use Perl language to interact with Quickbase ,I used the below query to export a data table into a text file but I am not getting right format I want, any thoughts? Or if there is another language  easier to interact with Quickbase?

```
@records = $qdb->doQuery($dbid,"{0.CT.''}","6.7.8.9"); 
$record_count = @records;

foreach $record (@records) {

  print MYFILE "|";

  foreach $field (keys %$record){
    if ($field eq "ColumnA") {
      print MYFILE "\"";
      print MYFILE " $field : $record->{$field}";
      print MYFILE "\"";   
    }

    if ($field eq "ColumnB") {
      print MYFILE "\"";
      print MYFILE "$field : $record->{$field}";
      print MYFILE "\"";
    }

    if ($field eq "ColumnC") {
      print MYFILE "\"";
      print MYFILE "$field : $record->{$field}";
      print MYFILE "\"";
    }

    if ($field eq "ColumnD") {
      print MYFILE "\"";
      print MYFILE "$field : $record->{$field}";
      print MYFILE "\"";
    }   
  }

  print MYFILE "\n";    
}

close LOGFILE;
```

Comment: it might help if you describe the format you want, vs. the format it's currently giving you.

Comment: There is almost certainly a way to get the output that you want. But as you don't tell anything about a) the format of the `$record` hash or b) the output format that you want, it's hard to see how we can be any help at all.

Answer (score 4):

Wondering, for what kind of answer type do you looking for? But...

> I am try to use Perl language to interact with Quickbase,

That's great. Perl is very powerful and suitable for (nearly) **any** task.

> I used the below query to export a data table into a text file

Not very concise code. It is probably a legacy code from an Excel or [BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC) person. Some comments:

- the code doing the *same* actions for every field. So, why do you need the `if` statemenents?
- Also, why need break each `print` into 3 separate `print`s?
- why do you need the `|` at the beginning of the line?
- you probably want to close `MYFILE` instead of the `LOGFILE`.

others

- it is strange to print to every cell the `field_name: field_value`, instead of create the column header, but YMMV - so maybe you need this.
- it is better to use lexical filehandles, like `$myfile` instead of the `MYFILE`
- the `foreach` could be written as `for` :)

> but I am not getting right format I want, any thoughts?

i'm unable to tell anything about the **your wanted format**, mainly because:

- you didn't said anything about what format do you want to get
- and, unfortunately, my crystal globe is on the scheduled maintenance. :)

> Or if there is another language easier to interact with Quickbase?

Probably **not**.

- The quickbase has an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) for the access, (you [can learn about it here](https://help.quickbase.com/api-guide/index.html), and every language (using some libraries) just does the bridge. For the perl it is the [HTTP::QuickBase](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::QuickBase) module. Did you read the doc?
- Perl is extremely powerful, so anyone can write very concise code. Just need learn the language (as any other one). (Unfortunately, I'am also closer to  beginners as experts.)

The above code is could be reduced to:

```
for my $record ($qdb->doQuery($dbid,"{0.CT.''}","6.7.8.9")) {
    print MYFILE '|',
                 join('|', map {
                           '"' . $_ . ': ' . $_->{field} . '"'
                      } keys %$record
                  ), "\n";
}
```

And will do exactly as the above.

But need to tell, it is still wrong solution. For example:

- need cope with the *quoting* e.g. the `"cell content"`.
- but also, the cell contents could contain also the `"` character, so you need espace them. Here are more escaping techniques for the `CSV` files, one of is doubling the quote character (usually the `"`). Or prepend them with `\`. And much more possible problems, like "new line" characters `\n` in the cells and so on.

To avoid `CSV` quoting/escaping hell and other possible problems with CSV generation, you should to use the [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module. It's been developed in the last 20 years, so it is very long time/hard/stress tested module. You could to use it as:

```
use Text::CSV;
use autodie;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { sep_char => '|', binary => 1 } ) #if you really want use the '|' instead of the standard comma.
               or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();
open $fh, '>', 'some.csv';
$csv->print( $fh, [map { $_->{field} } keys %$_]) for @$records;
close $fh;
```

Of course, the code is not tested. So, what next?

- learn about the [quickbase API module](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::QuickBase)
- learn about and install the [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module
- read some tutorials and docs about the Perl language itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers , I am still infant in perl  that's why I used some pre written script to get csv | delimited file . I will try to use text ::csv and the code suggested and see what will happen I will let you know

Comment: If someone can guide me to good materials for learning perl quickly

Comment: @Rakan you can use this online (or download) http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2014/ but you can buy form Addison Wesley: Learning perl, Intermediate perl and Mastering perl. Also here is many good blogs. Unfortunately, here are still too many _OLD_ sites, which teaches the _not very modern perl_  :( (for ex: using the very old CGI) Anyway, please read [tour] and [help] - asking for external resources is forbidden on this site.

Comment: Thanks a lot jm666 for your help , I have tried the below code but i am getting only |||||||   with no data !!   :

Comment: @records = $qdb->doQuery($dbid,"{0.CT.''}","6.7.8.9"); 
$record_count = @records;
print STDERR "Number of records returned for 01-29-2016 search is $record_count\n";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { sep_char => '|', binary => 1 } ) #if you really want use the '|' instead of the standard comma.
               or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();
open $fh, '>', 'C:\\Strawberry\\Quickbase_Log_files\\some.csv';
$csv->print( $fh, [map { $_->{field} } keys %$_]) for @$records;
close $fh;